# Symfony 1.4 form, conditional throwing sfValidatorError in embedded form

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have Page object:

```
Page:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    I18n:
      fields: [name,content,attachment,course_name, course_description ]
      actAs:
        Sluggable: { fields: [name], uniqueBy: [lang, name], canUpdate: true }
  columns:
  ...
    is_course:            { type: boolean }
    course_name:          { type: string(255) }
    course_description:   { type: string(500) }
```

And PageForm with embedded i18n forms:

```
//PageForm.class.php 
public function configure()
{
...  
    $this->embedI18n(array('pl','en'));
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('en', 'Angielski');
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('pl', 'Polski');
}
```

Fields course_name and course_description aren't required while is_course is set to false. But if is_course is enabled  validation should throw error that course_name and course_description are required.

I have readed "Symfony Advanced Forms" guide and some other posts, but I don't know should I use sfValidatorCallback in PageForm or PostValidator in PageTranslationForm? I tried to use sfValidatorCallback in this way:

```
//PageForm.class.php
public function configure()
{
...
       $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
          new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this,'checkCourses')))
          );
}

public function checkCourses($validator, $values)
{
    if($values['is_course'])
    {
      if($values['pl']['course_name'] && !$values['pl']['course_description'])
      {
          $error = new sfValidatorError($validator,'Required filed');
          throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array( _what_name_ => $error));
      }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

But i don't know how to throw  error in $values['pl']['course_description'] because  Symfony API says _what_name_ should be an array of errors..

I'm really confused what is what during process of validating forms in symfony.

//Edit

I have done some changes in PageTranslationForm and now it looks like this...
     //PageTranslationform.class.php

```
 public function configure()
 {
 //......

  $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
          new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this,'checkCourses')))
   );

 //.....
 }

public function checkCourses($validator, $values)
{
    if($values['course_name'] && !$values['course_description'])
    {
        $error = new sfValidatorError($validator,'Required');
        throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array( 'course_description' => $error));
    }
    elseif(!$values['course_name'] && $values['course_description'])
    {
        $error = new sfValidatorError($validator,'Required');
        throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array( 'course_name' => $error));

    }
    return $values;
}
```

And it almost works but... this validator should be enabled only if in PageForm is_course is set to "true".  How can I access field "is_course" from PageForm  in checkCourses function in PageTranslationForm?

//SOLUTION

Thanks Jeremy, I used your idea and finally got this solution:

```
//PageForm.class.php
public function configure()
{
    $this->embedI18n(array('pl','en'));
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('en', 'Angielski');
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('pl', 'Polski');

//.....
  if($this->getObject()->getIsCourse())
  {
      foreach($this->getEmbeddedForms()  as $key => $form)
      {
          $this->validatorSchema[$key]->setPostValidator(
             new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($form,'checkCourses')))
          );
      }
  }
}

//PageTranslationForm.class.php
//configure etc

  public function checkCourses($validator, $values)
  {
       $errorSchema =  new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator);


        if($values['course_name'] && !$values['course_description'])
        {
          $errorSchema->addError(new sfValidatorError($validator,'required'), 'course_description');
        }
        elseif(!$values['course_name'] && $values['course_description'])
        {
          $errorSchema->addError(new sfValidatorError($validator,'required'), 'course_name');
        }
        elseif(!$values['course_name'] && !$values['course_description'])
        {
          $errorSchema->addError(new sfValidatorError($validator,'required'), 'course_name');
          $errorSchema->addError(new sfValidatorError($validator,'required'), 'course_description');
        }


        if (count($errorSchema))
        {
          throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, $errorSchema);
        }

      return $values;
  }
```

Thanks for you advice, It works perfectly and  I hope it would be helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a post validator because you are using multiple values.

When validating via a post validator, you can throw the error in two different ways:

**Globally**

When the error is thrown globally, it will show up as part of `sfForm::renderGlobalErrors`. To throw globally, simply throw the error in the callback:

```
public function checkCourses($validator, $values)
{
  if ($invalid)
  {
    throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Required.'); //global messages should be more specific than this
  }
}
```

**Locally**

To have the error be rendered locally, throw a schema with an array, as you are doing. The keys of the array will determine the fields the errors are rendered on. This is probably want you want here.

```
public function checkCourses($validator, $values)
{
  if ($invalid)
  {
    $error = new sfValidatorError($validator,'Required filed');
    throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('course_description' => $error));
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, but only in PageTrasnaltionForm. Now I have to enable this PostValidator only if is_course in PageForm is set to true -  how to do it?

Comment: If is_course isn't mutable, you can check before adding the post validator. If it's part of the form, just keep it always enabled and  don't throw an error if is_course is false.